# SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Document'

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this issue

```
Caused by: 

 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Document'.
```

The document in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:setr.010.001.03">
```

My XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by Standards Editor (build:R1.0.42.1) on 2013 May 24 16:27:15, ISO 20022 version : 2013-->
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:setr.010.001.03" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:setr.010.001.03">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
```

I have a problem of ns. Any idea please ?

Regards

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Posting the XML and XSD may be helpful.

Comment: This the xml document xmlns <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:setr.010.001.03">

Comment: this the xsd schema <xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:setr.010.001.03" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:setr.010.001.03">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted XML and XSD are poorly formatted (currently invisible, in fact) and incomplete (as seen by peaking behind the scenes of your post).  The most we can say is that **the namespace of the root element does not match the target namespace of the XSD**.  You have a lot more work to do on your end if you want more help on this than that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem was the targetNamespace of the xsd != namespace of the XML.

Thank you